# React prevent MUI Select from changing width in MUI Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-select, column-width

I have an MUI grid setup with a variable number of columns. Currently, if the user selects a long string for the Select box, the Select grows, increasing the size of the entire column. However, I want each column to remain the same size, no matter what is selected (and truncate what's in the Select box).

Please see the images below for a better understanding. In these examples, there are 8 columns:

Unfilled: [empty fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dnS2.png)

Filled: [field filled, clearly the long text in the select box resized the whole column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQGKA.png)

Code:

```
{this.state.sampleData.map((obj, idx) => {
                  return (
                    <Grid item xs={true}> //Ensures the columns are the correct size (more columns = smaller widths).
                      <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                          <Typography>#{obj["#"]}</Typography>
                        </Grid>


                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                          <TextField
                            className={classes.smallTextField}
                            inputProps={{
                            ...
                            }}
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Name"
                            name="name"
                            value={
                              this.state.sampleData[idx].name || ""
                            }
                            onChange={(event) => {
                              this.handleChange(
                                event.target.value,
                                idx,
                                "name"
                              );
                            }}
                          />
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item xs={12}>
                          <FormControl
                            variant="filled"
                            fullwidth
                            size="small"
                            className={classes.selectFieldFormControl}
                          >
                            <InputLabel
                              sx={{ ... }}
                            >
                              Position
                            </InputLabel>
                            <Select
                              sx={...}
                              name="position"
                              value={
                                this.state.sampleData[idx].position || ""
                              }
                              onChange={(event) => {
                                this.handleChange(
                                  event.target.value,
                                  idx,
                                  "position"
                                );
                              }}
                            >
                              <MenuItem value="">
                                <em>None</em>
                              </MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem value={"manager"}>
                                manager
                              </MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem value={"factory"}>
                                factory
                              </MenuItem>
                              <MenuItem value={"assistant to the regional manager"}>
                                assistant to the regional manager
                              </MenuItem>
                            </Select>
                          </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        );})}
```

How can I get the  box to truncate the text inside it so that the column does not get resized? I figure I'll need to add some style in either the Select box itself or the parent grid item.

Thanks!

Comment: Give the `input` field `width` or `size`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp

Comment: @Azu the issue is I don't know what ```width``` or ```size``` to give it, since I don't know beforehand how many columns there are. The size will depend on the number of columns.

Comment: I see. Then could you give the columns the same width?

Comment: @Azu any idea how to do that? If there was some way to get the width of the column, I could give that value to every column, but I'm not sure how I can do that.

Comment: If you give the select container a static width in px, it will respect it, but I have the same problem, in that I want the select to adopt the width of the grid container, but not break out of it. If the select parent is set to 100%, for some reason it has the same problem :(

Comment: any update on how you solved this @stripedapus?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, adding a maxWidth of 100% to the grid item that contains the select, and making the width of the select 100% solved it for me:

```
<Grid item xs={12} lg={4} sx={{ maxWidth: "100% !important" }}>
      <h3 id="select-theme-label">Themes</h3>
      <Select
        id="select-theme"
        sx={{ width: "100%" }}
      ></Select>
</Grid>
```

Or probably more realistically, adding the right maxWidth responsively:

```
sx={{ maxWidth: { xs: "100% !important", md: "28% !important" } }}
```

Comment: I did this, put width and maxwidth to 100% on the children on the Grid but that didn't work for me.

Comment: post a sandbox...